# Applying vector of arguments of known size to virtual variadic function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, virtual, variadic-functions

in the following code example I am about to call concrete `foo()` function with already initialized arguments `vect` via `run()` method. For compilation I use VS19 with C++17. In the following I am not sure about my usage of `std::apply`... Any kind of help is welcomed ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template<typename ...T>
struct Base {
    vector<int> vect;
    Base(){
        static const std::size_t size = sizeof...(T);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            vect.push_back((i+1)*(i+1)); //some initialization
    }
};

template<typename ...T>
struct Derived : public Base<T...> {
    virtual int foo(T...) = 0;

    int lastResult;

    void run() {
        if (this->vect.size() > 0) {
            lastResult = std::apply(foo, this->vect);
        }else{
            lastResult = -1;
            cout << "0 arguments case" << endl;
        } 
    }

};


struct D0 : public Derived<> {
    int foo() override { return 0; } 
};

struct D1 : public Derived<int> {
    int foo(int a) override { return a * a; } 
};

struct D2 : public Derived<int,int> {
    int foo(int a, int b) override { return a + b; }
};


int main() {
    D0 d0;
    cout << d0.foo() << endl; // 0
    //d0.run(); //vect = {}, lastResult = -1, "0 arguments case"

    D1 d1;
    cout << d1.foo(1) << endl; // 1
    //d1.run(); //vect = {1} -> lastResult = 1

    D2 d2;
    cout << d2.foo(1, 2) << endl; // 3
    //d2.run(); //vect = {1,4} -> lastResult = 5


    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Since you know at compile time how many elements are going to be stored in `vect`, you can use `std:array` instead, which does with with `std::apply`.  Or do you need to change the size after construction?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thank you for the reply. At the moment, for the kind of objects I create there is no need to change their size. But in the future of the project I am also interested in potentially growing the size after construction. What would be your suggestion for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::index_sequence` from C++14 helps with this kind of stuff:

Make a second version of run that takes a sequence of `size_t` template arguments, and use `std::index_sequence_for` to fill them:

```cpp
template <size_t... Is>
void runImpl(std::index_sequence<Is...>) { ... }

void run() { return runImpl(std::index_sequence_for<T...>{}); }
```

Then, in `runImpl`, you can expand the template integers to pass vector values as function parameters:

```cpp
if (this->vect.size() > 0) {
    lastResult = foo(Base<T...>::vect[Is]...);
}else{
    lastResult = -1;
    cout << "0 arguments case" << endl;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ZGroAH

Comment: This works perfectly right out of the box! There are some new concepts for me to learn as well.

Answer (score 0):

> In the following I am not sure about my usage of  `std::apply`...

I see two problems in your usage of `std::apply()`

(1) `std::apply()` require a `std::tuple`, or similar, for second argument. For "or similar" I mean "or `std::array` or `std::pair`".

So your `std::vector` doesn't works.

I suppose you can use a `std::array`.

I propose the following `Base`

```
template<typename ...T>
struct Base {
   std::array<int, sizeof...(T)> vect;

   template <int ... Is>
   Base (std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) : vect {{ (Is+1)*(Is+1) ... }}
    { }

   Base () : Base{std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(T)>{}}
    { }
};
```

(2) the first argument of `std::apply()` isn't compatible with a (non static) method.

But you can wrap it's use in a lambda, so I propose

```
        lastResult = std::apply([=](auto ... args)
                                { return this->foo(args...); },
                                this->vect);
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking down insufficiency for my code. As next I need to get my hands of lambdas to follow your solution in details.